# Break down XML files using SQL Server into individual rows

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

Here's what I'm doing. I'm inserting an XML file into an XML column, along with other columns such as date stamps etc. for logging (those are irrelevant to this request)

The file looks like something similar to this:

```
<topLevelItem>
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>
    </secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
    </secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>
    </secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
    </secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>
    </secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
    </secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
<topLevelItem>
```

My goal is to be able to query the XML field and get a result set with each `<secondLevelItem>` in it's own row, in it's XML form. Such as below:

Row 1:

```
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>
    </secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
    </secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
```

Row 2:

```
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>
    </secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
    </secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
```

Row 3:

```
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>
    </secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
    </secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
```

This has to be done using Microsoft SQL Server and without using CLI. I need to be able to declare which XML node I want the break down to start at, as some files have additional XML elements that I don't require. So something like, `WHERE node = secondLevelItem`.

Answer (score 3):

With SQL Server 2005 and newer, there's excellent XQuery support in SQL Server.

This approach here would be using the `.nodes()` and `.query()` method:

```
SELECT 
    Col.query('.')
FROM 
dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY
    YourXmlColumn.nodes('/topLevelItem/secondLevelItem') AS Tbl(Col)
WHERE
    (some condition)
```

The `.nodes()` function creates a "temporary, inline" pseudo table `Tbl` with a single column `Col` which contains one XML entry for each node in your XML column that matches the XPath given (in this case: each `<secondLevelItem>` inside the `<topLevelItem>` will be matched).

Since you want the entire XML for each of those XML elements, just use the `.query('.')` to return that complete XML element.

Answer (score 2):

Use [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) to shred your XML and use [local-name()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190650.aspx) and [sql:variable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx) to find the node you want, retrieve the XML with [query()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx).

```
declare @NodeName varchar(100) = 'secondLevelItem'

select T.N.query('.')
from YourTable
  cross apply XMLCol.nodes('//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@NodeName")]') as T(N)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just supplying the original XML to a stored procedure and not pulling it from a table you could do the following.

```
DECLARE @XML xml
SET @XML = '<topLevelItem>
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>One</secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>One One</secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>Two</secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>Two Two</secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
  <secondLevelItem>
    <secondLevelItemDetail>Three</secondLevelItemDetail>
    <secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>Three Three</secondLevelItemAnotherDetail>
  </secondLevelItem>
</topLevelItem>'


SELECT 
    Tbl.Col.query('.')
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('/topLevelItem/secondLevelItem') AS Tbl(Col)
```